# html5 MKV playback with subtitles

Tags: html, subtitle, mkv, webvtt, vtt

I am attempting to play an MKV file in my chrome browser with subtitles so I can view local video files. This has been successful, using the above method/code in Microsoft Edge, however, when I use chrome I am unable to see the subtitles (cannot use Firefox as MKV was unsupported)

```
<video id="video" controls preload="metadata" style="width:80%;height:80%">
   <source src="file.mkv" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="file.mkv" type="video/webm">
   <track label="language one" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="sub.vtt">
   <track label="language two" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="sub.vtt">
</video>
```

[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JceJf.png)

- chrome MKV player     //(root directory)
- file.mkv                 //(The video file)
- file.vtt                 //(The subtitle file)
- RUN.html                 //(The html file that displays the video)

This method was based off of this github repository ["https://github.com/iandevlin/iandevlin.github.io/tree/master/mdn/video-player-with-captions"](https://github.com/iandevlin/iandevlin.github.io/tree/master/mdn/video-player-with-captions)

I have:

- tried using different subtitle formats (vtt, stl, ass, srt)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the primary language must be tagged with default?

```
<track label="language one" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="sub.vtt" default>
```

Works for me, haven't tried without. Otherwise I'd guess there's something wrong with the .vtt file.